# How do you add !important to a CSS-in-JS (JSS) class property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use some CSS-in-JS classes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525334/how-can-i-change-the-label-size-of-a-material-ui-textfield/54525703#54525703) with a material UI component in my React project. I need to override the CSS coming from Bootstrap so I want to use the !important modifier, I've only used this in .css files before and I'm unsure how to do it in CSS-in-JS. My styles object to be passed into the Material-UI `withStyles` function looks like the following, how do I add !important to the fontSize attribute? I've tried `30 !important` and a few other things but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

```
const styles = {
  labelRoot: {
    fontSize: 30
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't use important

Comment: @AdrianBrand so you can't use important in inline CSS? Is it automatically the most important?

Comment: Inline styles have the highest precedence or specificity in a document

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074748/important-inline-styles-in-react

Comment: @AdrianBrand - a css rule having `!important` trumps inline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style `!important` the same way inline that you would in css.

In the below example, both divs are styled `blue !important` in css, but the pink div has important also inline, and so takes precedence.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue !important;
  flex:1;
}
section{display:flex;}
```

```html
<section>
  <div style="background: red;"></div>
  <div style="background: pink !important;"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't need to do this as Adrian points out, but if you absolutely need to do it you can set it to a string:

```
const styles = {
  labelRoot: {
    fontSize: '30px !important',
  },
};
```

Comment: If this was the recommended syntax at some point, it is not now, and doesn't work with function values. The answer by @Andres9619 is what the official documentation suggests, and (unsurprisingly) works for all cases.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [array-based syntax](https://cssinjs.org/jss-syntax/?v=v10.0.4#alternative-syntax-for-space-and-comma-separated-values) for space and comma separated values.

Just do this:

```
const styles = {
  labelRoot: {
    fontSize: [[30], '!important'],
    margin: [[5, 10], '!important']
  }
}
```

Comment: This also works with function properties, so 
- fontSize: (size) => [[size], '!important'] - 
Whereas the other options *do not*.